# angular2: service with a template?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to create a service for showing alerts (in case sending a form goes wrong). This will be used on various forms of my project so I thought I could use an independant service for this. The problem is: for this alert I need HTML code at a certain place of my form, so what I need to know is : what's best practice for that?

Can I define a template for my service? And how do I use this template in my form wihch uses the service?

Comment: What do you use for your alerts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a difficult time using angular2 packages for notifications then I decided to create my own notification for a system I'm working on. I scrapped online till I found [Mathew Ross' Post](https://matthewross.me/blog/posts/notifications-an-angular-2-component) Check it out and see if it guides you, somehow.

Comment: that is exaclty what I was looking for! I copied this to start from it but unfortunately _notifications.noteAdded.subscribe is never called - any idea why this might happen? I copied the exact same code and there is no error message

Comment: @Chi mine works well... could you post the code for you notification component maybe I could help better?

Comment: seems I just imported the service at the wrong place, I finally managed to make it work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If showing alerts means showing a popup then it should be a component. Components have a view that is added to the DOM.

You can share a global service that allows other components, directives and services to communicate with your `AlertsComponent` and pass strings or component types to be shown in the alert. For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

I would use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` like demonstrated in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) to display arbitrary components as content of the alert if you need custom HTML support with Angular bindings in the alert content.

Comment: could you maybe give me a very basic example of how to do that ?

Comment: Please provide more details about your requirements first.

Comment: what exactly do you need? basically its a form and when saving the form I want to show a success (or error) alert - and this alert should be re-usable on other forms. My template requires some html on a certain place in the html structure for it to display correctly

Comment: Does the HTML need to contain binding expressions (components, directives, `[prop]=...`, `(event)=...`, ...)?

Comment: this is how I used it before in the form html: <alert [alertModel]="alertModel"></alert>

Comment: What is `alertModel`?